# How to capture results of regex and replace patterns in bash

Tags: regex, bash

Bash scripting does my head in. I have searched for regex assignment, but not really finding answers I understand.

I have files in a directory. I need to loop through the files and check if they fit certain criteria. File names under a certain sequence need to have their sequence increased. Those over a certain sequence need to trigger an alert.

I have pseudo code and need help turning it into correct bash syntax:

```
#!/bin/sh

function check_file()
{
    # example file name "LOG_20101031144515_001.csv"
    filename=$1

    # attempt to get the sequence (ex. 001) part of file

    # if sequence is greater than 003, then raise alert

    # else change file name to next sequence (ex. LOG_20101031144515_002.csv)
}

for i in `ls -Ar`; do check_file $i; done;
```

If PHP were an option, I could do the following:

```
function check_file($file){
    //example file 'LOG_20101031144515_001.csv';

    $parts = explode('.',$file);
    preg_match('/\d{3}$/', $parts[0], $matches);
    if ($matches){
        $sequence = $matches[0];
        $seq      = intval($sequence);

        if ($seq > 3){
            // do some code to fire alert (ex. email webmaster)
        }
        else{
            // rename file with new sequence
            $new_seq  = sprintf('%03d', ++$seq);
            $new_file = str_replace("_$sequence", "_$new_seq", $file);
            rename($file, $new_file);
        }
    }
}
```

So long story short, I'm hoping someone can help port the PHP check_file function to the bash equivalent.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your question is tagged `[bash]`, but your shebang is `#!/bin/sh`. I'm going to assume Bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
function check_file()
{
    # example file name "LOG_20101031144515_001.csv"
    filename=$1

    # attempt to get the sequence (ex. 001) part of file

    seq=${filename%.csv}
    seq=${seq##*_}

    # if sequence is greater than 003, then raise alert

    if (( 10#$seq > 3 ))
    then
        echo "Alert!"
    else
        # else change file name to next sequence (ex. LOG_20101031144515_002.csv)
        printf -v newseq "%03d" $((seq + 1))
        echo "${filename/$seq/$newseq}" # or you could set a variable or do a mv
    fi
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback; it looks very close to what I am trying to do. However, I copied the code verbatim into a test file and it's throwing the following error about the function's final closing curly bracket: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Comment: Again, thank you. I got beyond curly bracket syntax issue; the script was missing "fi" to close the if block. Also, the script was missing the bit to increment the seq; I added that as "seq=$(( seq + 1 ))". Now I am stuck on the substitution in the last echo. In the line, echo "${filename%%$seq.csv}$newseq.csv", $seq is not being replaced by $newseq. Rather the "$newseq.csv" is being appended and the resulting output is LOG_20101031144515_001.csv002.csv rather than LOG_20101031144515_002.csv

Comment: Success! After some hunting, I found the bash substitution pattern and replaced the echo line in Dennis' code, with: echo "${filename/$seq/$newseq}

Comment: @Jordan: Sorry about the omissions and errors. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

PHP **IS** an option. If you master PHP, you can run it from shell.
Run

```
php myfile.php
```

and get the output right into console. If the PHP file is executable and begins with

```
#!/path/to/php/executable
```

then you can run

```
./myfile.php
```

I'm no big expert in bash programming, but in order to obtain the list of files that match a certain patter you can use the command

```
ls -l | grep "pattern_unquoted"
```

I suggest you to go for the PHP ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I won't be running the script from command line. It will live in a cronned shell script.

Comment: +1: If Jordan can program PHP and not Bash, then PHP is probably the way forward... particularly if Jordan is the one who is going to have to maintain the script.

Comment: @Jordan: If you can run from the command-line, you can run from Cron.

Answer (score 3):

A different take on the problem:

```
#!/bin/sh

YOUR_MAX_SEQ=3

find /path/to/files -maxdepth 1 -name 'LOG_*.csv' -print \
  | sed -e 's/\.csv$//' \
  | awk -F_ '$3 > SEQ { print }' SEQ=$YOUR_MAX_SEQ
```

Brief explanation:

- Find all files in `/path/to/files` matching LOG_*.csv
- Chop the `.csv` off the end of each line
- Using `_` as a separator, print lines where the third field is greater than `$YOUR_MAX_SEQ`

This will leave you with a list of the files that met your criteria.  Optionally, you could pipe the output through `sed` to stick the `.csv` back on.

If you're comfortable with PHP, you'd probably be comfortable with Perl, too.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. However it does not seem to handle the part about incrementing the sequence on files where current sequence is less than 3 and then saving file name with new incremented file name

Comment: Replace the `print` in the `awk` with `printf "%s_%s_%03d.csv\n", $1, $2, $3+1 }' SEQ=$YOUR_MAX_SEQ`.

Comment: Oops...  The `SEQ=$YOUR_MAX_SEQ` doesn't belong in my last comment.